# "IllegalArgumentException: null source" on the default datasource after adding another datasource (Grails 2.1.2)

Tags: grails, datasource, grails-orm

I am having problem when I try to add another datasource (grails 2.1.2, mysql-connector-java 5.1.21)

1. Added the second data source (dataSource_customer) in a config file

   ```
   dataSource {
       url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/defsource"
       username = "defsource"
       password = "defsource"
   }

   dataSource_customer {
       url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/customer_db"
       username = "customer"
       password = "customer"
   }
   ```

2 Defined a new class, set datasource to customer

```
class SensitiveDataExample {
    String analysisName

    static constraints = {
        analysisName nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 50
    }

    static mapping = {
        datasource('customer')
    }
}
```

With this I can access SensitiveDataExample without a problem. However when I try to access any other domain object, I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
   at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
   at org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent.<init>(ApplicationEvent.java:42) ~[spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
   at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEvent.<init>(AbstractPersistenceEvent.java:48) ~[grails-datastore-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.SaveOrUpdateEvent.<init>(SaveOrUpdateEvent.java:20) ~[grails-datastore-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:106) ~[grails-hibernate-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(SavePersistentMethod.java:58) ~[grails-hibernate-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56) ~[grails-hibernate-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:212) ~[grails-hibernate-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63) ~[grails-hibernate-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
   at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231) [springloaded-core-1.1.0.jar:1.0.0]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189) ~[groovy-all-1.8.8.jar:1.8.8]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53) ~[groovy-all-1.8.8.jar:1.8.8]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42) [groovy-all-1.8.8.jar:1.8.8]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) [groovy-all-1.8.8.jar:1.8.8]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124) [groovy-all-1.8.8.jar:1.8.8]
   at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:909) ~[grails-hibernate-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
```

Preliminary troubleshooting indicates that the (data)source passed to SaveOrUpdateEvent() and onwards is null.

I tried to explicitly add the datasource as DEFAULT for the other domain objects, which did not help.

This exception is not seen if I simply comment out dataSource_customer.